# Shared, ephemeral read-only Docker volume

Tags: docker

I'm working on a Docker-based setup for a simple web-app running in Nginx+php-fpm. The common suggestion I've seen for storing the actual PHP code is to store it on the host and then mount it read-only in both the Nginx and PHP containers.

However, I want my setup to be self-contained so I can easily use it on Amazon ECS with Auto Scaling. In other words, I want to bundle the code somehow, rather than pulling it from the host.

So it seems what I want is a read-only volume that can be shared between two Docker containers and won't persist after those containers are destroyed. Is this possible? Or is there a better approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker images can contain volumes that are pre-populated with data. To achieve this, in the `Dockerfile`, first populate a the directory (for example using `COPY` or `RUN`) and then declare it as a volume. This allows you to build an image that contains your application code inside a volume:

```
FROM php:7-fpm

COPY ./app /var/www/html
VOLUME /var/www/html
```

Creating a new container from this image will create a new volume, initialize it with the data from the image's `/var/www/html` directory and mount it inside your new container at the same location.

Compare [the documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#volume) for more information:

> The docker run command initializes the newly created volume with any data that exists at the specified location within the base image. For example, consider the following Dockerfile snippet:
>
> ```
> FROM ubuntu
> RUN mkdir /myvol
> RUN echo "hello world" > /myvol/greeting
> VOLUME /myvol
> ```
>
> This Dockerfile results in an image that causes `docker run`, to create a new mount point at `/myvol` and copy the `greeting` file into the newly created volume.

This allows you to simply start your application image with `docker run`:

```
docker run -d --name app my_application_image
```

Then you can run your Nginx container and configure it to use the same volumes as your application container using the `--volumes-from` flag:

```
docker run -d --name web --link app:app --volumes-from app my_nginx_image
```

After this, you will have a Docker volume containing your application code that is mounted in both containers at `/var/www/html`.

Comment: But does this cover the "ephemeral" part of my question? From my understanding, this method would leave orphaned volumes around after my containers are terminated, which I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: The container's volumes should be deleted together with the container, at least when using the [`--volumes` or `-v` flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/rm/#/options).